# Setting message rules with Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Ive been working on a powershell script to use Graph API to set mailbox rules. Basically ive followed this [guide](http://cloudcompute.info/create-custom-folder-in-exchange-online-mailboxes-using-graph-api-using-windows-powershell/) I can get folder creation to work as per the guide, But when I try and edit the script and replace body with this [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-post-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create the message rule it fails. I'm struggling to work out why. Anyone have any ideas where I might be going wrong?

```
    ## Details for mailboxes and folders needed. Obviously you can get these as parameters if need be.
    For AdHoc code I use "Get-Clipboard" quite often. Here a fixed array as something to start with.

$Mailboxes = @("mailbox")

## Before next step aquire access token, if you need help this blog has a great example https://adamtheautomator.com/microsoft-graph-api-powershell/. For simplicity, I have used here an application secret.

# Define AppId, secret and scope, your tenant name and endpoint URL
$AppId = "ID"
$AppSecret = "Secret"
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$TenantName = "name"

$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Add System.Web for urlencode
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# Create body
$Body = @{
    client_id = $AppId
    client_secret = $AppSecret
    scope = $Scope
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}

# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Method = 'POST'
    # Create string by joining bodylist with '&'
    Body = $Body
    Uri = $Url
}

# Request the token!
$Request = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat

# Create header
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}

## Thanks, now we have token ready for use. Lets use GRAPH's mailFolders API

## Loop through mailbxoes

foreach($mailbox in $Mailboxes) {

    $Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$mailbox/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules"


$Body = @"
{      
    "displayName": "Test",      
    "sequence": 2,      
    "isEnabled": true,          
    "conditions": {
        "importance": [
          "low"       
        ]
     },
     "actions": {
        "copyToFolder": [
          "Low Priority"       
        ],
        "stopProcessingRules": true
     }    
}
"@

   $NewRule = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json"
   
   

}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The error I'm getting is:   

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Ry Files\Powershell\mailrule.ps1:67 char:15
+ ...  $NewRule = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method Post ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Answer (score 0):

Your post syntax is incorrect neither importance or copyToFolder are meant to be arrays, also the folder should be the id of the folder not the name. So a successful post should look like

```html
{      
            "displayName": "Test",      
            "sequence": 2,      
            "isEnabled": true,          
            "conditions": {
                "importance": "low"
             },
             "actions": {
                "copyToFolder": "AAMkADczNDE4YWEwLTdlZmItNDIzZC04MDViLTYyYjI2YmRh....",
                "stopProcessingRules": true
             }    
}
```